# VB for MS Access not working when using INNER JOIN

Tags: vba, ms-access, inner-join

The code isn't working properly, getting a Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement error.  Trying to insert data with an inner join from an MS Access form where the user types in responses and selects a button to add the detail to a new table.  Based on the information provided I want it to insert the data into another table where it is joined by a table to get the fiscal data.

```sql
    stSQL = "INSERT INTO PO_Information " & _
        "(Partner, PO_Number, PO_Title, Cost_Center, Description, Line_1_Amt, Line_2_Amt, Date_Added, Month_Added, Year_Added, FY, Qtr, FY_Qtr, FW, FWeek)" & _
        "Select New_PO_Information.Partner, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.PO_Number, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.PO_Title, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.Cost_Center, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.Description, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.Line_1_Amt, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.Line_2_Amt, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.Date_Added, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.Month_Added, " & _
        "New_PO_Information.Year_Added, " & _
        "Fiscal_Calendar.FY, " & _
        "Fiscal_Calendar.Qtr, " & _
        "Fiscal_Calendar.FY_Qtr, " & _
        "Fiscal_Calendar.FW, " & _
        "Fiscal_Calendar.FWeek, " & _
        "From New_PO_Information INNER JOIN Fiscal_Calendar " & _
        "ON New_PO_Information.Date_Added = Fiscal_Calendar.Calendar"


    stSQL = stSQL & _
        "From New_PO_Information " & _
        "Where ((New_PO_Information.Partner)<>'') " & _
        "AND ((New_PO_Information.PO_Number)<>'') " & _
        "AND ((New_PO_Information.PO_Title)<>'') " & _
        "AND ((New_PO_Information.Cost_Center)<>'') " & _
        "AND ((New_PO_Information.Description)<>'');"
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong and correct the code, please?

Comment: "isn't working properly" - _how exactly_ is it not working? Are you getting errors, or unexpected output, or does everything freeze?

Comment: Use `Debug.Print`: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: When it runs, I get a Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: This line looks really suspicious to me: `"From New_PO_Information " & _`.

Comment: I tried removing the "," like you recommended but received another error message.  If I wrote an append query it works.  Here is the append query, I just wanted to turn it into the code below that I wrote originally.

Comment: still not working, I tried below recommendation and not working.  If I use an append query it works but that's not what I am trying to do.

Comment: Did you `Debug.Print strSql` and put result in query designer (sql view), like Andre suggested? Response?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably this comma here: `"Fiscal_Calendar.FWeek, " & _`

There shouldn't be a comma before the `FROM` statement. And make sure you only have one FROM statement:

```
 stSQL = "INSERT INTO PO_Information " & _
    "(Partner, PO_Number, PO_Title, Cost_Center, Description, Line_1_Amt, Line_2_Amt, Date_Added, Month_Added, Year_Added, FY, Qtr, FY_Qtr, FW, FWeek)" & _
    "Select New_PO_Information.Partner, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.PO_Number, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.PO_Title, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.Cost_Center, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.Description, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.Line_1_Amt, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.Line_2_Amt, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.Date_Added, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.Month_Added, " & _
    "New_PO_Information.Year_Added, " & _
    "Fiscal_Calendar.FY, " & _
    "Fiscal_Calendar.Qtr, " & _
    "Fiscal_Calendar.FY_Qtr, " & _
    "Fiscal_Calendar.FW, " & _
    "Fiscal_Calendar.FWeek " & _
    "FROM New_PO_Information INNER JOIN Fiscal_Calendar " & _
    "ON New_PO_Information.Date_Added = Fiscal_Calendar.Calendar"


stSQL = stSQL & _
    " Where ((New_PO_Information.Partner)<>'') " & _
    "AND ((New_PO_Information.PO_Number)<>'') " & _
    "AND ((New_PO_Information.PO_Title)<>'') " & _
    "AND ((New_PO_Information.Cost_Center)<>'') " & _
    "AND ((New_PO_Information.Description)<>'');"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I created an append query, here is the code.  Just trying to convert this into my SQL statement that I posted earlier.

INSERT INTO PO_Information ( Partner, PO_Number, PO_TItle, Cost_Center, Description, Line_1_Amt, Line_2_Amt, Date_Added, Month_Added, Year_Added, FY, Qtr, FY_Qtr, FW, FWeek )
SELECT New_PO_Information.Partner, New_PO_Information.PO_Number, New_PO_Information.PO_TItle, New_PO_Information.Cost_Center, New_PO_Information.Description, New_PO_Information.Line_1_Amt, New_PO_Information.Line_2_Amt, New_PO_Information.Date_Added, New_PO_Information.Month_Added, New_PO_Information.Year_Added, Fiscal_Calendar.FY, Fiscal_Calendar.Qtr, Fiscal_Calendar.FY_Qtr, Fiscal_Calendar.FW, Fiscal_Calendar.FWeek
FROM New_PO_Information INNER JOIN Fiscal_Calendar ON New_PO_Information.Date_Added = Fiscal_Calendar.Calendar;

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Also re line breaks. Please in an answer explain don't just give code, explain code would be what the asker wants and what their problem was. [answer]